Cloudinary API fails to initialise api key when used with Django signals
I made a signal receiver for a model UserFiles and named it upload_to_cloudinary. This receiver calls a function inside it, which uploads a file to cloudinary.
This works well enough if the receiver upload_to_cloudinary is inside the same models.py as UserFiles but when I refactored it to signals.py file in the same app and registered in apps.py it is starts to throw error:
raise ValueError("Must supply api_key")
ValueError: Must supply api_key 

I expected it to work similarly after refactoring but certainly it doesn't I have all the configurations down in the settings.py file.

this can happen if your Cloudinary credentials are not set properly. Can you confirm how you are setting them?

i did this ```CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {
"CLOUD_NAME": os.environ.get("CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME"),
"API_KEY": os.environ.get("CLOUDINARY_API_KEY"),
"API_SECRET":  os.environ.get('CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET'),
}


hey @Tom I resolved it by directly adding cloudinary.config(     cloud_name= os.environ.get("CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME"),     api_key=os.environ.get("CLOUDINARY_API_KEY"),     api_secret=os.environ.get('CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET'),     secure=True ) to wsgi.py, rather than letting cloudinary module handle it by itself.
